# How can I know which organisation a special command line tool is belong to?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx

Frequently we use command line tools to do fancy things in UNIX like system; many of them have a manpage and typically we can know which orgnization/person owns the copyright.
For example, on Mac OS X we know that `gobjdump` is one of `GNU Development Tools` and `Free Software Foundation` has the copyright. On Linux, we can also know that `tmux`'s manpage is classified into `BSD General Commands Manual`.

But I find there are other tools from whose manpages we cannot infer the organization they belong to. 
For example, `man top` on Debian it tells:

```
display Linux processes
```

But `man top` on Mac OS X, it displays:

```
display and update sorted information about processes
```

They don't have canonical GNU/BSD manpage like the above and I cannot even infer whether they have any relationship.

So how can we get more information about these tools? Are there any webpages telling these?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit of a hunt to find this info. Some options are:

**Read the Documentation**

If you run `top -v` you'll see the line `procps-ng version x.x.x`

`procps-ng` is the package that contains `top` along with other tools such as `ps`.

You can read the licence for the `procps-ng` package in `/usr/share/doc/procps-ng-<x.x.x>/COPYING`

In this case, it's a copy of the GPL, therefore `top` comes under the GPL.  You can also Google for `procps-ng` and read up.

The above was on my system and should be very similar on your Debian.  The OSX machine may be different though.

Another avenue to find the documentation would be to use your package manager to search for the package that provides the binary then list all the files in that package - that should hopefully give you the documentation where you should find the licence.

**Read the Source**

The Google search showed that `procps-ng` is hosted on Gitorious.  You can view the source on there or you can install the source package on your distro and read it.  The top few lines of `top.c` are:

```
/* top.c - Source file:         show Linux processes */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by: James C. Warner
 *    All rights reserved.      8921 Hilloway Road
 *                              Eden Prairie, Minnesota 55347 USA
 *
 * This file may be used subject to the terms and conditions of the
 * GNU Library General Public License Version 2, or any later version
 * at your option, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Library General Public License for more details.
 */
/* For contributions to this program, the author wishes to thank:
 *    Craig Small, <csmall@small.dropbear.id.au>
 *    Albert D. Cahalan, <albert@users.sf.net>
 *    Sami Kerola, <kerolasa@iki.fi>
 */
```

This states that it's under the GPL.

**Command's Usage Option**

Other commands might help you if you ask for their usage.  For example:

```
$ bash --help
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release-(x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

The above, on my Fedora system, shows that it's GNU `bash`, therefore it also will be under the GPL licence.

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

`grep` states the licence in it's `--version` option.

Comment: Thanks for these informative words; seems the copyright issue is really a mess for these tools. Basically I hope there are some website listing frequently-used tools and their owners; so presently I'd upvote but not mark as correct, in hope to see if there are other answers:-)